# How do I edit prebuilt Classes in my project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, class, dll

I have a dll file that has three classes in it that somebody else built. I was wondering how I  could edit the classes. I know I can because I accidentally had an error with one of them and it took me to the code of that class but not the one I want to edit. I already have permission to edit them. If you can help please do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only edit it if you have the source code.

Comment: One option would be to create a new class that inherits that one and overload the methods you want to change.